# Most lightweight method of data for Android-consumed web service

Tags: android, json, web-services, rest

I'm working on an Android app that consumes a web service that has the potential to return quite a lot of data. The web service is also goingto be built by my team, and we're looking into ways of transferring data to the client with the least amount of load. We've looked into REST and SOAP, and can't decide between the two. Would JSON be a good alternative? We might need to fetch quite a lot of data in some use cases.

We'd really rather not use SOAP, if can avoid it. The emphasis is on reducing the work needed to be done on the Android system as much as possible.

Could anybody please help us out? As far as technology scope is concerned, we have full freedom of choice as long as we stay within the JAVA umbrella.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Not sure how to add comments, so I'll do it here(I read the FAQs, but couldn't find the necessary section)

Hi,

Let me start by apologising for my vague problem statement, I was actually a bit rushed when I posted the query. Anyway, to answer your questions, by "a lot of data", I mean that there are going to be ba few large requests(2-3, depending on the use case) that MIGHT return a lot of data, e.g. if I search using the entity name(complete or partial), the result, which is going to be textual data only, would be considerably less than if the serach was made with country as a search parameter, in which case it might return several hundred separate results. One particular search parameter has the potential to return a few thousand rows of data. What we can control is the amount of data in each row(so to speak) returned. Currently, we're attempting to reduce the items to display per row(we're attempting to keep it below 5). It's a business decision, I'm afraid, so if we're stuck with the current scenario of 12 items per row, we need to be prepared for that as well, I'm afraid.

Comment: "We've looked into REST and JSON, and can't decide between the two" -- that's like saying "we've looked into snowplows and oranges and can't decide between the two". REST and JSON aren't substitutes for one another. "with the least amount of load" -- load in terms of... what? Bandwidth? RAM? CPU? Flash storage? Battery life? Developer time? "quite a lot of data" -- what sort of data? Images? Relational-style rows-and-columns of strings and numbers? Movies? Audio clips? "Could anybody please help us out?" -- start by more clearly defining what you are returning and what your criteria are.

Answer (score 0):

What you just said was the equivalent of "i cannot decide between unleaded and 15" tyres".

Restful web services tend to be lighter than soap but there are use cases for both. They are both technologies used to deliver service orientated architecture. For you small description I would use rest although with more detail there may be a case for soap. You say a lot of data but does this mean many small requests or a few large ones?

Your restful web service may return a variety of data formats such as xml, yaml and json. Json's syntax makes it lighter than xml so that could be a good choice. Examples of this sort of setup include Facebook's open graph api and drupal's services module.

Comment: Ok, but is there a size limit for the amount of data I can transfer using JSON? That was my primary concern, actually: Getting a lot of data while keeping android-side processing to a minimum. So, if I were to send a large amount of data as JSON, and then parse it sith say, Google GSON, wouldn't that cause a significant processing overhead?

Comment: @user1148258 - how complex is your data?  If it's key-value pairs, you can use something easier to parse than JSON, or if it's a table.  If it's structured data, you're going to have some overhead dealing with it no matter what.